# Where to add persistent/networking code in a MVVM architecture

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I'm trying to make a project for learning purpose using `MVVM`. I get the idea on how this pattern works, but all of the examples I found are very basic and don't explain where exactly you add your persistent/networking code.

I am trying to use `Core Data` in my project.
Does someone has experience with this pattern ? I am reading that this kind of code should go in a `NSOperation`. Does this make sense ?

Any other thoughts ? I am just looking for some advice from other people who done this.

For now I am not interested in a Reactive approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since asynchronous networking code can stay live well outside (and past) anything to do with the current UI, it should probably be put in a model object or other separate controller object, completely outside the view, view controller or view model hierarchy.  Perhaps in a network controller object (custom class) attached at the app delegate level, so that networking state can be retained and gracefully shut down or handled in the background.